# Angular - wait for this variable to have value and then execute

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

In `ngOnInit()`, first line of code fetches the `value` from local storage and then that value is used to `filter` data from database.

*Both executes together* and I don't get the result. How can I do something like the second function *waits* for the first one to get value.

Below is my `ts` code:

```
 ngOnInit() {

    //get id of user
    this.storage.get('loggedInUser').then((val) => {
      console.log('Your user ID is', val);
      this.loggedInusr = val;
    });

    firebase.firestore().collection(`todos`)
  .where("assignTo", "==", this.loggedInusr) // don't get value here, if I hard code all works
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          console.log("assignTo");
          console.log(doc.id, " ===> ", doc.data());
      });
    });

    ...
```

Comment: Hi user2828442. I've edited a lot of chatty material from your questions in the past, and you will have received the notifications from the Stack Overflow platform. Some of your material has a needy, begging quality, and suggests you think that displays of helplessness will cause people to pity your situation and/or feel coerced into the social obligation of assisting the less fortunate. This is not appropriate behaviour for a volunteer platform. Please stick to technical writing.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the 2nd procedure inside the handling of 1st procedure. Try the following

```js
ngOnInit() {
  //get id of user
  this.storage.get('loggedInUser').then((val) => {
    console.log('Your user ID is', val);
    this.loggedInusr = val;

    firebase.firestore().collection(`todos`)
      .where("assignTo", "==", this.loggedInusr) // dont get value here, if i hard code all works
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log("assignTo");
            console.log(doc.id, " ===> ", doc.data());
        });
      });

  });
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: this worked, 1 question, how do i change change `.get()` to `.valueChanges()` so that if new record is inserted under this filter, user gets it

Comment: I would say `valueChanges()` should be called separately since it's a persistent call. Here you depend on the value of `this.loggedInusr` for the call. So if you call `valueChanges()` it will use the same `this.loggedInusr` every single time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use rxjs switch map for that, then if any values change in observable this will update automatically

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';

     from(this.storage.get('loggedInUser'))
      .pipe(switchMap((loggedUser) => 
              from(firebase.firestore().collection(`todos`).where("assignTo", "==",loggedInusr) .get()).subscribe(querySnapshot => {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                console.log("assignTo");
                console.log(doc.id, " ===> ", doc.data());
            });
    ))
```

Comment: thanks, i'll try this and get back -  1 question, how do i change change .get() to .valueChanges() so that if new record is inserted under this filter, user gets it in real time

Comment: simply these rxjs are related to observable u can change what u want as observable then all the new updaes are availble without any code changes