# Pre assign value in Quill JS editor

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, quill

I have added Quill JS on `home.html`. I am assigning it a value from a variable. It is showing the `pre assigned value`, but it is not showing its html property.

Here is my `home.html` code::

```
<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="editorForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="editor">
        <h3>Editor</h3>
      </label>
  <quill-editor [(ngModel)]="dhtml" formControlName="editor"></quill-editor>
</div>
<ion-button type="submit">Submit</ion-button>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

and `home.ts` code::

```
export class DesigntemplatePage implements OnInit {

  loggedInusr;
  editorForm: FormGroup;
  dhtml = '<p><font color="red">This is some text!</font></p>';

  form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    html: new FormControl(null)
  })
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,private storage: Storage,private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.storage.get('loggedInUser').then((val) => {
      console.log('Your user ID is', val);
      this.loggedInusr = val;
    });
    this.editorForm = new FormGroup({
      'editor': new FormControl(null),
    })
  }

  OnSubmit(){
    console.log(this.editorForm.get('editor').value);
  }
```

It is showing text inside the editor, but not in red color, see image below -

[image]

### Edit 1

I have created a **safepipe**, on adding it, I can see red text using `innerHtml` but this text is not showing inside the Quill JS editor.

```
  <quill-editor [innerHtml]="dhtml| safe3: 'html'" formControlName="editor"></quill-editor>
```

See image below:

[image]

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: You should use either ngModel (old forms) or formControlName (Reactive Forms).

Comment: @halfer if "please guide" is also not allowed, i'll take care of it in future. If any more issues please shoot to me. Please understand, its the way we all talk so it was natural , will take care, any other issue found ?

Comment: @ekalin can you explain with sample code for better understanding ?

Comment: @ekalin as guided by you, i am now doing this `<quill-editor [(ngModel)]="htmlText"
  placeholder="Enter Text"
  ></quill-editor>` old forms way. But still it is not showing coloe inside editor

Comment: I appreciate the reply. It's not about it not being "allowed" - it's about you understanding that your readers are volunteers here, and begging is highly inappropriate. Moreover, it is good for question authors to understand that Stack Overflow is not a platform for free work. You have many questions where you seem to be asking for someone to finish your project in each case, [here is one of many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898341/angular-wait-for-this-variable-to-have-value-and-then-execute). In many cases these are just abandoned.

Comment: Moreover, you've received at least two hundred edits to your material, and it still features the same lack of effort every time, with apparently no willingness to improve. No spell checking, misuse of formatting, etc.

Comment: i will try to improve